# Rotate list in OCaml

Tags: list, rotation, ocaml

I want to write a function `rotate n l` that returns a new list containing the same elements as `l`, "rotated" `n` times to the right. For example,

> `rotate 0 [1;2;3;4]` should return `[1;2;3;4]`
>   `rotate 1 [1;2;3;4]` should return `[4;1;2;3]`
>   `rotate 2 [1;2;3;4]` should return `[3;4;1;2]`
>   `rotate 3 [1;2;3;4]` should return `[2;3;4;1]`
>   `rotate 4 [1;2;3;4]` should return `[1;2;3;4]`
>   etc.

The behavior of `rotate n` for `n` less than 0 should be the same as for `n` equal to 0.
I want to write this without using the list concatenation operator `@` from `Pervasives`.

**Update:** Here is the rotation function I wrote:

```
let rot1 l =
  let rec iterate acc = function
      [] -> []
    | [x] -> x :: List.rev acc
    | x :: l -> iterate (x :: acc) l
  in
  iterate [] l;;
```

But I want it to do the same thing without using `List.rev`.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This looks very much like homework. It's hard to help without just giving you the answer unless you show some code you've tried and describe how and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Jeffrey, show us what you tried. Here's a small hint in case you need to get started. If you can write a function that performs only 1 rotation i.e. equivalent to `rotate 1 l`. (I call it `one_rot`). Then `rotate` can be easily defined as:

```
let rec rotate n l = 
  match n with 
  | 0 -> l
  | _ -> rotate (n-1) (one_rot l)
```

Your solution is perfectly fine for me. Not sure what you have against List.rev but here's a completely stand alone `one_rot`. Note that we have to sacrifice tail recursion. You could probably make this quite a bit shorter too:

```
let rec last = function
  | [] -> assert false 
  | [x] -> x
  | x::xs -> last xs

let rec init = function
  | [] -> []
  | [x] -> []
  | x::xs -> x::(init xs)

let one_rot l = (last l)::(init l)
```

Comment: let rot1 l =
  let rec iterate acc = function
      [] -> []
    | [x] -> x :: List.rev acc
    | x :: l -> iterate (x :: acc) l
  in
  iterate [] l;;

Comment: thanks for the tip. I know how to write this whole thing if i could use the list functions. but i don't know how to write it without it. So i have written the one_rot l function and it  works but i use the List.rev function. Is there a way to write that without the List.rev?

Comment: what does assert false do exactly here?

Comment: gives an error when you pass an empty list. you can omit that clause but you will get a warning for inexhaustive pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by combining these 3 functions:

cat(skip(list, places), take(list, places))

The implementation looks like:

```
let rec cat = function
    ([], y) -> y
    | (x::xs, y) -> x :: cat (xs, y)

let rec skip = function
    ([], _) -> []
    | (_::xs as xs1, c) -> if c > 0 then skip(xs, c - 1) else xs1

let rec take = function
    ([], _) -> []
    | (x::xs, c) -> if c > 0 then x :: take(xs, c - 1) else []

let cycle l i =
    cat (skip (l, i), take (l, i))
```

cycle ([1;2;3;4;5;6], 3);;

val it : int list = [4; 5; 6; 1; 2; 3]